# How to plot stacked barchart from categorical and numerical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, stacked-chart

I have given some state names with their total opened and closed complaints all three are stored in a list.
I want to plot a stacked bar plot showing states in the x-axis where each state's bar shows opened and closed complaints in the stacked form. I tried it myself to but I am constantly getting an error,

```
shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

This is the code I am using

```py
# plotting stack bar chart
indx = list(range(len(states)))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
graph_state = plt.bar(x=indx, height=states, width=0.35)
graph_closed = plt.bar(x=indx, height=closed, width=0.35, bottom=states)
graph_opened = plt.bar(x=indx, height=opened, width = 0.35, bottom=closed+states)
plt.xlabel('States')
plt.ylabel('Complaints')
plt.show()
```

and here is data I used

```py
states = ['Maryland','Georgia','Michigan','California','NewMexico','Indiana','Virginia','Illinois','Pennsylvania','Massachusetts','Oregon','Texas','NewHampshire','Minnesota','Tennessee','Colorado','Florida','Alabama','Washington','NewYork','NewJersey','Maine','Missouri','WestVirginia','Montana','Mississippi','Connecticut','Vermont','Kentucky','SouthCarolina','Ohio','Utah','Delaware','Arkansas','Nevada','Louisiana','Kansas','Arizona','North Carolina','Rhode Island','District Of Columbia','District of Columbia','Iowa']
opened = [15,80,23,61,4,9,11,29,20,11,13,22,4,4,47,22,39,9,23,19,2,1,3,16,3,1,3,3,6,4,1,1,6,2]
closed = [63,208,92,159,11,50,49,135,110,50,36,49,8,29,96,58,201,17,75,6,56,3,3,8,1,23,9,2,4,15,3,16,8,6,1,12,1,14,3,1,14,1,1]
```

Comment: Oops!! Sorry but that's not the error I am getting

Comment: It appears that your opened has few elements than states and closed.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes it likes that

Comment: For which `states` do you not have data in `opened`?

Comment: You might want to add  `plt.xticks(..., rotation=90)` and `plt.tight_layout()`

Answer (score 0):

I can get the plot to work if I pad the "opened" list to have the same length (43) as "states" and "closed"

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states = ['Maryland','Georgia','Michigan','California','NewMexico','Indiana','Virginia','Illinois','Pennsylvania','Massachusetts','Oregon','Texas','NewHampshire','Minnesota','Tennessee','Colorado','Florida','Alabama','Washington','NewYork','NewJersey','Maine','Missouri','WestVirginia','Montana','Mississippi','Connecticut','Vermont','Kentucky','SouthCarolina','Ohio','Utah','Delaware','Arkansas','Nevada','Louisiana','Kansas','Arizona','North Carolina','Rhode Island','District Of Columbia','District of Columbia','Iowa']
opened = [15,80,23,61,4,9,11,29,20,11,13,22,4,4,47,22,39,9,23,19,2,1,3,16,3,1,3,3,6,4,1,1,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
closed = [63,208,92,159,11,50,49,135,110,50,36,49,8,29,96,58,201,17,75,6,56,3,3,8,1,23,9,2,4,15,3,16,8,6,1,12,1,14,3,1,14,1,1]

indx = list(range(len(states)))
width = 0.35

p1 = plt.bar(indx, opened, width)
p2 = plt.bar(indx, closed, width,
             bottom=opened)
plt.ylabel('opened')
plt.xticks(indx, states, rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```